# What causes NameError: name '...' is not defined?

Tags: python

I have these requirements.

[image]

I got this far:

```
def main():
     a_tickets_sold = int(input('How many A tickets were sold?: '))
     b_tickets_sold = int(input('How many B tickets were sold?: '))
     c_tickets_sold = int(input('How many C tickets were sold?: '))
     d_tickets_sold = int(input('How many D tickets were sold?: '))

def calculate_class_incomes():
    a_total = a_tickets_sold * 30
    b_total = b_tickets_sold * 30
    c_total = c_tickets_sold * 30
    d_total = d_tickets_sold * 30

main()
calculate_class_incomes()
```

I get this error: NameError: name 'a_tickets_sold' is not defined

Comment: Do you have a specific question? See also **[mcve]**.

Comment: Please tell us what is your real problems here.

Comment: I keep getting this error: NameError: name 'a_tickets_sold' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for your code:

```
def main():
 a_tickets_sold = int(input('How many A tickets were sold?: '))
 b_tickets_sold = int(input('How many B tickets were sold?: '))
 c_tickets_sold = int(input('How many C tickets were sold?: '))
 d_tickets_sold = int(input('How many D tickets were sold?: '))

 a_income, b_income,c_income,d_income = calculate_class_incomes(a_tickets_sold ,b_tickets_sold ,c_tickets_sold ,d_tickets_sold )

def calculate_class_incomes(a_tickets_sold,b_tickets_sold ,c_tickets_sold ,d_tickets_sold):
 a_total = a_tickets_sold * 30
 b_total = b_tickets_sold * 20
 c_total = c_tickets_sold * 15
 d_total = d_tickets_sold * 10

 return a_total,b_total,c_total,d_total
```

Comment: Than how would I go about adding the show_total_income() function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def main():
 a_tickets_sold = int(input('How many A tickets were sold?: '))
 b_tickets_sold = int(input('How many B tickets were sold?: '))
 c_tickets_sold = int(input('How many C tickets were sold?: '))
 d_tickets_sold = int(input('How many D tickets were sold?: '))
 return a_tickets_sold,b_tickets_sold,c_tickets_sold,d_tickets_sold

def show_total_income(a_total,b_total,c_total,d_total):
    print(sum([a_total,b_total,c_total,d_total]))

def calculate_class_incomes(a_tickets_sold,b_tickets_sold,c_tickets_sold,d_tickets_sold):
    a_total = a_tickets_sold * 30
    b_total = b_tickets_sold * 30
    c_total = c_tickets_sold * 30
    d_total = d_tickets_sold * 30   
    return show_total_income(a_total,b_total,c_total,d_total)

a_tickets_sold,b_tickets_sold,c_tickets_sold,d_tickets_sold = main()
calculate_class_incomes(a_tickets_sold,b_tickets_sold,c_tickets_sold,d_tickets_sold)
```

In the main function you will be having 4 variables. after compilation of main function those 4 variables will be returned and stored in respective variables where we called the main function. Then those variables will be passed to calculate_class_income function, there you can easily use those 4 variables.

Comment: can you add some explanations for me this is awesome i really appreciate it

Comment: how would I add that show_total_income() I keep getting errors